# How to reduce the value of a column in a row with?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

I have a table with two columns:

```
No   Value
1    20
2    10
3    50
4    35
5    17
```

I also have a variable or parameter where the variables will reduce the value of a column in a row.

So, if my variable `V = 5` then my column will update:

```
No   Value
1    15
2    10
3    50
4    35
5    17
```

Or if `V = 50` then:

```
No   Value
1    0
2    0
3    30
4    35
5    17
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Based on what logic do you filter the data, if your `V` variable is 5 or 50 ? (Why did you put 0's for 15 and 10 if `V` is 50?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @qty int

SET @qty= 50


WHILE @qty> 0
BEGIN

SELECT @qty= @qty- value
FROM table
WHERE no = (SELECT MIN(no) FROM table WHERE value > 0)

IF @qty< 0
    BEGIN
     UPDATE table
     SET value = ABS(@qty)
     WHERE (SELECT MIN(no) FROM table WHERE value > 0)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
     UPDATE table
     SET value = 0
     WHERE (SELECT MIN(no) FROM table WHERE value > 0)
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

First prepare the structure and the data:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB
(
  [No] int identity(1,1) primary key,
  [Value] int
);

INSERT INTO TAB VALUES (20);
INSERT INTO TAB VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO TAB VALUES (50);
INSERT INTO TAB VALUES (35);
INSERT INTO TAB VALUES (17);
```

So now we define your variable to reduce the [Value]:

```
DECLARE @var int
SET @var = 5
```

And now you can query your table:

```
SELECT [No], CASE WHEN [Value] - @var < 0 THEN 0 ELSE [Value] - @var END AS [Value] 
FROM TAB
```

Very easy. You can set your variable to 50 an try again.
Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8eb64/4) for this example.

Comment: The logic implemented in your `CASE` statement is not correct. For example subtracting 5 from the first two numbers will return `15` and `10`, whereas your logic, based in input data, will return `15` and `5`. So, not the exact answer but the most likely assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE can be one of the options

```
declare @Values table
(
    [No] int identity(1,1) not null,
    Value int not null
)

declare @DeductAmount int = 50

INSERT @Values VALUES (20), (10), (50), (35), (17)

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, 
        @DeductAmount -  CASE WHEN Value >= @DeductAmount THEN @DeductAmount ELSE Value END AS RemainDeductAmount, 
        Value - CASE WHEN Value >= @DeductAmount THEN @DeductAmount ELSE Value END DeductedValue 
    FROM @Values WHERE [No] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        v.*,  
        cte.RemainDeductAmount - CASE WHEN v.Value >= cte.RemainDeductAmount THEN cte.RemainDeductAmount ELSE v.Value END, 
        v.Value - CASE WHEN v.Value >= cte.RemainDeductAmount THEN cte.RemainDeductAmount ELSE v.Value END DeductedValue
    FROM @Values v INNER JOIN cte ON v.[No] = cte.[No] + 1
)
UPDATE target SET Value = DeductedValue
FROM @Values target INNER JOIN cte ON target.[No] = cte.[No]

SELECT * FROM @Values
```

The secret inside the cte

```
No          Value       RemainDeductAmount DeductedValue
----------- ----------- ------------------ -------------
1           20          30                 0
2           10          20                 0
3           50          0                  30
4           35          0                  35
5           17          0                  17
```

Answer (score 0):

Change 50 with your variable

Query:

```
SELECT t.No,
       CASE WHEN SUM(t.Value)over(ORDER BY t.No) - 50 <0 THEN 0
           WHEN SUM(t2.Value)over(ORDER BY t2.No) > 50
                AND SUM(t.Value)over(ORDER BY t.No) >50 THEN t.Value
           ELSE SUM(t.Value)over(ORDER BY t.No) - 50
       END AS Value
FROM Table1 t
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2 ON t.No - 1 = t2.No
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) , v INT )
DECLARE @x INT = 5

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ( 20 ), ( 10 ), ( 50 ), ( 35 ), ( 17 );

WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        @x - ( SELECT   ISNULL(SUM(v), 0) AS v
                               FROM     @t t2
                               WHERE    t2.ID <= t1.ID) s
               FROM     @t t1
             )
    SELECT  ID ,
            CASE WHEN s >= 0 THEN 0 
                 WHEN s < 0 AND v + s > 0 THEN -s 
                 ELSE v END
    FROM    cte
```